# How do you diagnose which relationship the Entity Framework is referring to?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Upon updating a complex object (with several related child objects) and calling `SaveChanges`, I am getting the error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be...

I've had a look at the exception raised and there doesn't appear to be any contextual information. How do I know which relationship/s is/are causing the error?

Comment: What changes are you making to said object? Which child objects which are linked via foreign key are non-nullable? More context would be helpful.

Comment: I suggest using the dbcontext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s)  or similar logging method to see the sql that EF is running. Then you can run the statements one by one to see which gives a sql error.

Comment: Thanks Mike, will take a look.  Ryan, it's more of a broad question around diagnosing issues raised by the EF as the EF just gives a generic error message; which would be fine if you only had one relationship.  But when you have a dozen or more relationships, many with one or more sub-relationships and have no indication which relationship the EF is referring to it becomes problematic.

Comment: Did you happen to check if the inner exception has anything useful?

Comment: Hi Yoshi, yes indeed.  Always check the inner exception, always see if you can capture it as the correct error type as it often will reveal more useful information, but in this case, the inner exception is null and type casting the error didn't provide any additional information.